# Где и как отловить исключение "Invalid input value. Use Escape key to abandon changes"?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, где и как можно отловить исключение `EDBEditError` для `TMaskEdit`, появляющееся, когда этот самый `TMaskEdit` теряет фокус? (если значение введено не до конца и фокус теряется, то выскакивает сообщение `"Invalid input value. Use Escape key to abandon changes."`)

Comment: событие onchange обрабатывайте

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Только отнаследоваться от TCustomMaskEdit и перекрыть ValidateEdit и или ValidateError.

Там проблема в том что maskedit сам ловит виндовое сообщение CMExit и по нему проверяет ввод. Т.е. до OnExit и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

**try**

**except**

**finaly**

В помощь

Answer (score 0):

Есть решение. Нашел - кину:

```
    procedure TForm1.MaskEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
    begin
     TMaskEdit(Sender).Modified := False;
    end;
```